# How to call a core template in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am new to Magento, and I have created `list1.phtml` in Magento with some changes to the file `list.phtml`. My problem is that I want to call `list1.phtml` like `list.phtml`. I  copied the code of `list.phtml` from `catalog.xml` and created a new content block for  `list1.phtml` but it doesn't work for me. Please help.

Actually, I want a page in Magento that only shows 5 product rows, and all other pages are the same with 3 products. I am overriding `list.phtml` to `list1.phtml` according to my needs but it doesn't work for me.

Sorry for my English.

Thanks in advance,

-Jeet

Comment: Please post the XML that you copied for the new template.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to create a new template by creating a new folder inside `/app/design/frontpage/default`. Copy the `list.phtml` there keeping the directory structure intact. Then choose this newly created template in the custom design section for the category that you want this custom `list.phtml` to apply to.

Let me know if any of the above requires more clarification and I will be more than happy to help you out further.

Comment: jeet, @silvo is suggsting that you create a new folder at `/app/design/frontpage/default/seconddesign/template/catalog/product` and copy your `list.phtml` into there.  Then, in the web admin interface of Magento, go to `Catalog>Manage Categories` and select the category you want to change.  Click the `Custom Design` tab within that category and choose "seconddesign" from the drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

```
             <reference name="content">     
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">    
            <block type="catalog/product_list1" name="product_list1" template="catalog/product/list1.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                 <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>          
    <!--CODE END-->
```

Comment: You need to leave the block's `type` attribute the same as for list.phtml, so it would be:
`<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list1" template="catalog/product/list1.phtml">`.

Answer (score 0):

If you created core template named in catalog directory with name test.phtml.
Use:

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="core/template" name="tesitng"  template="catalog/test.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

:) Hope this works